# Box alignment matters CSS

Tags: html, css

Initially box were aligned this way, where all of them has flex properties.

i want it to be align like example, this is for Nav-bar alignment.

i have tried flex-direction: column,

the hamburger bar will appear when the screen size is less than certain px

[example, after the screen shrink to <800px](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RVBfY.png)

[The desktop resolution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rcYW4.png)

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 1035px) {
  .line {
    display: none;
  }

  .logo,
  .nav-links li a,
  .button {
    /*display: none;*/
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <a href="index.html" class="logo"
    ><img src="images/logo/1.svg" alt="" width="250px"
  /></a>
  <nav>
    <ul class="nav-links">
      <li><a>Explore</a></li>
      <li><a>About</a></li>
      <li><a>Pricing</a></li>
      <li><a>Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
  <div class="line"></div>
  <a class="register">
    <button>Register</button>
  </a>
  <div id="nav-icon1">
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
    <span></span>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: It is confusing what exactly do you want?  You should add [minimal reproducible code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: i want to align nav item in column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to use `display:flex` before using `flex-direction`. These are flexbox properties that create a flexbox of all the child elements inside a parent container.

Here the parent element is `<nav>` and the child elements are - all the navbar `<li>` links.

This should work for you if you wish to align the navbar in a column.

CSS

```
 .nav-links{
     display: flex;
     flex-direction: column;
     justify-content: center;
     align-items: center;
     list-style-type: none;

    }
```

Also, `align-items` helps to align the child items along the horizontal axis.

Also, you should ideally segregate the styling for all different elements, to improve readability of code and avoid confusion. :)

Comment: Thx  bro, it really helps me out !